# $.when and callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a neater way to do this:

```
    var f1 = function(){};
    var f2 = function(){};
    doSomething('ArbritraryString',f1); //does xhr, and then runs f1 on callback
    doSomething('ArbritraryString',f2); //does xhr, and then runs f2 on callback

    $.when($.get('myJson',f1,f2)).then(function(ret1, ret2, ret3){

        //doStuff
    });
```

Any ideas?

the `doSomething` function literally just calls the empty f1/f2 functions so I have a callback handler for `$.when` atm....

ideally I would want

```
$.when($.get('myJson',doSomething('ArbritraryString',function(){}); ,doSomething('ArbritraryString',function(){}))).then(function(ret1, ret2, ret3){

    //doStuff
});
```

and have jquery magically know that the 2nd param in doSomething is the callback it has to watch for.

`doSomething` looks like this:

```
doSomething:function(name,callbackFunction){
    /*snip logic 

    */
    $.get(name, function(data){
            /*some more logic 


            */

            if(typeof(callbackFunction)==='function'){
                callbackFunction();
            }
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: What part of this do you wish to be "neater"?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Its a xhr that loads a script and then $.when happens afterwards. I'm trying to figure out how I can rewrite this so I don't have to declare 2 empty functions outside a function parameter.

Comment: Can you modify `doSomething`? What does it return?

Comment: Why do you need `jQuery.when`? ["Since the `jQuery.get` method returns a `jqXHR` object, which is derived from a Deferred object, we can attach handlers using the `.then` method."](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

Comment: I am firing multiple xhr requests ( in this case 3), and only need something to happen after all 3 have returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `doSomething` so it does not accept a callback and simply returns the jqXHR object (end with `return $.get`), then you can use `$.when` correctly to track the progress of all the jqXHR objects:

```
$.when(
        doSomething('ArbritraryString'),
        doSomething('ArbritraryString'),
        $.get('myJson')
    ).done(function(ret1, ret2, ret3){
        // all three succeeded
    });
```

If `doSomething` needs to do some additional processing of some kind before it should be considered *resolved*, then this function should create its own Deferred object and return the value of that object's `.promise()` instead of returning `$.get` directly. For more on this approach, see the example at [deferred.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/).